# Interaction between two user controls in windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I created two user controls which called `UserControl1` and `UserControl2`, `UserControl1` contains `TextBox1` and `UserControl2` contains `Button1`. In the `UserControl2`, I want to get `TextBox1.Text` from `UserControl1` when click `Button1`.

This is revelant code:
In `UserControl1`:

```
 public partial class UserControlA: UserControl
{
    public UserControlA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TexBoxText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

In `UserControl2`:

```
 public partial class UserControlB: UserControl
{
    public UserControlB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here is to get textbox1.text
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you exposed on `UserControlA` a property to get to the `Text` value of `TextBox1`?  `TextBox1` is not externally accessible so you will need to create a function or property on `UserControlA` to get to it from `UserControlB`.

Comment: Either UserControl1 needs a reference to UserControl2 or the other way round

Comment: I created `TextBoxText` property to get to the `Text` value of `TextBox1`

Comment: matcheek, which way to create reference to `UserControl1`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is passing UserControlA instance to UserControlB's constructor.

```
public partial class UserControlB: UserControl
{
    UserControlA userControlA;

    public UserControlB(UserControlA ucA)
    {
        userControlA = ucA;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myString = userControlA.TexBoxText;
    }
}
```

Comment: In line `UserControlA userControlA;` occurs error, I can't find `UserControlA` in `UserControlB`.

Comment: @TuanNguyen: What's the error you get? Hope both UserControls are in the same namespace?

Comment: Both UserControls are not in the same namespace, I created `Windows Forms Control Library` to create two `User Control`

Comment: @TuanNguyen: Then you have to import the namespace ie: using xxx.xxx.UserControlA;

Comment: You mean I have to add reference to UserControlB??

Comment: @TuanNguyen: Correct. Because you want to use it inside UserControlA. UserControlB should know about UserControlA.

Comment: CharithJ, Unfortunately, error occured when I drag and drog `UserControlB` into Form. Error: `There is no this component that may be placed on toolbox`. I think error at line `public UserControlB(UserControlA ucA)`

Comment: @TuanNguyen: In this case you cannot drag and drop these UserControls. You will have to create those instances in code behind and add to controls programmatically. Eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768133/programmatically-changing-form-controls

Comment: Another example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205530/windows-form-c-sharp-change-user-control-by-code

Answer (score 0):

In `UserControl1`:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public TextBox TextBox
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1;
        }
    }
}
```

In `UserControl2`:

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    private TextBox txt = null;
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public TextBox TextBox
    {
        set
        {
            txt = value;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt != null)
            MessageBox.Show(txt.Text);
    }
}
```

In above controls' container:

```
uc2.TextBox = uc1.TextBox;
```